# Display content without submitting the answer

Tags: javascript

I want the quiz app to automatically go to the next question when the answer is chosen by the user but the way this is setup, the user has to click **submit** answer then **next** then it goes to the next question.

I want to remove the button completely.

Demo: http://output.jsbin.com/eRiSUhIB/1/

**Javascript:**

```
var quiz = [{
  "question": "What is the full form of IP?",
  "choices": ["Internet Provider", "Internet Port", "Internet Protocol"],
  "correct": "Internet Protocol"
}, {
  "question": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
  "choices": ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak"],
  "correct": "Bill Gates"
}, {
  "question": "1 byte = ?",
  "choices": ["8 bits", "64 bits", "1024 bits"],
  "correct": "8 bits"
}, {
  "question": "The C programming language was developed by?",
  "choices": ["Brendan Eich", "Dennis Ritchie", "Guido van Rossum"],
  "correct": "Dennis Ritchie"
}, {
  "question": "What does CC mean in emails?",
  "choices": ["Carbon Copy", "Creative Commons", "other"],
  "correct": "Carbon Copy"
}];


// define elements
var content = $("content"),
  questionContainer = $("question"),
  choicesContainer = $("choices"),
  scoreContainer = $("score"),
  submitBtn = $("submit");

// init vars
var currentQuestion = 0,
  score = 0,
  askingQuestion = true;

function $(id) { // shortcut for document.getElementById
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function askQuestion() {
  var choices = quiz[currentQuestion].choices,
    choicesHtml = "";

  // loop through choices, and create radio buttons
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    choicesHtml += "<input type='radio' name='quiz" + currentQuestion +
      "' id='choice" + (i + 1) +
      "' value='" + choices[i] + "'>" +
      " <label for='choice" + (i + 1) + "'>" + choices[i] + "</label><br>";
  }

  // load the question
  questionContainer.textContent = "Q" + (currentQuestion + 1) + ". " +
    quiz[currentQuestion].question;

  // load the choices
  choicesContainer.innerHTML = choicesHtml;

  // setup for the first time
  if (currentQuestion === 0) {
    scoreContainer.textContent = "Score: 0 right answers out of " +
      quiz.length + " possible.";
    submitBtn.textContent = "Submit Answer";
  }
}

function checkAnswer() {
  // are we asking a question, or proceeding to next question?
  if (askingQuestion) {
    submitBtn.textContent = "Next Question";
    askingQuestion = false;

    // determine which radio button they clicked
    var userpick,
      correctIndex,
      radios = document.getElementsByName("quiz" + currentQuestion);
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) { // if this radio button is checked
        userpick = radios[i].value;
      }

      // get index of correct answer
      if (radios[i].value == quiz[currentQuestion].correct) {
        correctIndex = i;
      }
    }

    // setup if they got it right, or wrong
    var labelStyle = document.getElementsByTagName("label")[correctIndex].style;
    labelStyle.fontWeight = "bold";
    if (userpick == quiz[currentQuestion].correct) {
      score++;
      labelStyle.color = "green";
    } else {
      labelStyle.color = "red";
    }

    scoreContainer.textContent = "Score: " + score + " right answers out of " +
      quiz.length + " possible.";
  } else { // move to next question
    // setting up so user can ask a question
    askingQuestion = true;
    // change button text back to "Submit Answer"
    submitBtn.textContent = "Submit Answer";
    // if we're not on last question, increase question number
    if (currentQuestion < quiz.length - 1) {
      currentQuestion++;
      askQuestion();
    } else {
      showFinalResults();
    }
  }
}

function showFinalResults() {
  content.innerHTML = "<h2>You've complited the quiz!</h2>" +
    "<h2>Below are your results:</h2>" +
    "<h2>" + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " questions, " +
    Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + "%<h2>";
}

window.addEventListener("load", askQuestion, false);
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", checkAnswer, false);
```

Comment: You should put submit listeners on the form, not the submit button (why do people keep doing that?), so `form.addEventListener('submit',...)` and the listener should return *false* to cancel submit.

Comment: That's not really a submit button and there's no form. What are you talking about?

Comment: @PHPglue why did you delete your answer, it did not work!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should totally do what you want :). Hope it helps!

```
  var quiz = [{
      "question": "What is the full form of IP?",
      "choices": ["Internet Provider", "Internet Port", "Internet Protocol"],
      "correct": "Internet Protocol"
    }, {
      "question": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
      "choices": ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak"],
      "correct": "Bill Gates"
    }, {
      "question": "1 byte = ?",
      "choices": ["8 bits", "64 bits", "1024 bits"],
      "correct": "8 bits"
    }, {
      "question": "The C programming language was developed by?",
      "choices": ["Brendan Eich", "Dennis Ritchie", "Guido van Rossum"],
      "correct": "Dennis Ritchie"
    }, {
      "question": "What does CC mean in emails?",
      "choices": ["Carbon Copy", "Creative Commons", "other"],
      "correct": "Carbon Copy"
    }];


    // define elements
     var content = $("content"),
     questionContainer = $("question"),
     choicesContainer = $("choices"),
     scoreContainer = $("score"),
     submitBtn = $("submit");

  // init vars
  var currentQuestion = 0,
  score = 0,
  askingQuestion = true;

  function $(id) { // shortcut for document.getElementById
   return document.getElementById(id);
  }

  function askQuestion() {
  var choices = quiz[currentQuestion].choices,
   choicesHtml = "";
  }
```

Comment: @zyxcom, well - he has besically carbon copied my answer, where is the difference? -> **https://www.diffchecker.com/ghpmfbyd** (active for 1 day) at least ridiculous to downvote the original answer.

Comment: @zyxcom @xpng This is exactly what I want! I don't want the button to appear though!!! would removing `submitBtn.textContent = "Submit Answer";` be the way to remove it?

Comment: all I did to remove the button was delete this piece of code `<p><button id="submit"></button></p>` my quiz app is working perfectly! Thank you so much!!!!! @xpng